# How can I Display UserControl into a form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have created a UserControl and I want when I click on some button to display this UserControl into my form.

Is there any way to do that ?

Comment: You can treat your user control just like you do any other control that is added to a form.  So, if it's hidden, in the button click event, just call `UserControl.visible = true;`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can dynamically add the user control to the forms Controls collection.

For example, in the button click event handler:

```
MyUserControl uc = new MyUserControl();
uc.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
this.Controls.Add(uc);
```

Answer (score 0):

Put it on the form.  Start it out invisible, when the button is clicked set it to visible.

Comment: yes i know this method but I have many UserControls in my form and if I did this method I'll have difficulty to manage all these UserControls which are in the form, If there is a way to add this user control to the form without drag and drop method it would be great

Comment: In addition to making it invisible, you could move it out of the way to a non visible part of the form.  And when you make it visible, move it to where it needs to be.

Answer (score 0):

Drag your user control to your form and change it's Visible property to false

```
UserControl1.Visible = false;
```

Then on your button set the Visibility of your usercontrol to true.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UserControl1.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: check the comment I did to @Steve Wellens's answer

Answer (score 0):

Is it a typical ascx type of control? If yes then you can set the "visible" property of the control through the button click event.

Let say you have :

```
<uc1:ft ID="userctrl"  runat="server" Visible="false" />
```

then on your button event:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    userctrl.Visible = true;
}
```