# Winforms MVP Pattern w/ Multiple Views

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, mvp, tablelayoutpanel

I recently created a winforms application that followed no specific design pattern. This application has 4 different "views", each implemented using a TableLayoutPanel. One view is a "main" view that allows the user to select input files and the other 3 views contain DataGridViews that allow the user to work with the data loaded from the input file.

The problem lies in the fact that I have a single form with 4 different panels within it that are hidden and made visible when needed. But this has caused my form class to become much larger than I would like considering I have different events and methods that operate on the data for each panel all within the same class. So I did some research and came across Model-View-Presenter, but I've only came across examples that show applications with single-views.

My question is, if I use MVP and each view has its own interface and presenter, and the concrete implementation of the view is done using a Form, what is the best way to switch between views (for example, when clicking "next").

Should the concrete implementation of my view even be a Form? Am I missing something here? I'd like to follow the MVP pattern but I am open to suggestions if there is a better alternative.

Comment: When I've done this in the past I've created each view as a UserControl that implemented a specific custom interface,  for example `IWizardView`.  then a lil bit o code to select the proper view, perhaps using a statefull `WizardViewFactory` with `Next()` and `Prev()` methods.  Just one option.

Comment: UserControl is the best way to handle this

Comment: you can take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12647473/how-can-i-display-usercontrol-into-a-form

Comment: Thanks! I'll implement using UserControl and follow up with my solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you want to create a UserControl for each of the three DataGridView forms. As you are using MVP, each one should have an interface that the control inherits. For example:

```
public interface IDataGridView1
{
    // Properties, Methods, etc...
}

public interface IDataGridView2
{
    // Properties, Methods, etc...
}

public interface IDataGridView3
{
    // Properties, Methods, etc...
}
```

Here is an example of the DataGridView1 UserControl, which inherits from its interface, and also from `Control`:

```
public class DataGridView1 : Control, IDataGridView1
{
    TableLayoutPanel layoutPanel;

    public DataGridView1()
    {
        layoutPanel = new TableLayoutPanel();
        // Set up the layoutPanel.

        // Rest of constructor, define your controls.

        // Add your controls to layoutPanel.

        // Add layoutPanel to this control.
        Controls.Add(layoutPanel);
    }

    // Methods etc...
}
```

The other two DataGridViews will be similar but with their own functionality.

You could then create an interface for the MainView, which includes properties for the three DataGridViews it should contain, and methods to show one DataGridView whilst hiding the rest:

```
public interface IMainView
{
    IDataGridView1 DataView1 { get; set; }
    IDataGridView2 DataView2 { get; set; }
    IDataGridView3 DataView3 { get; set; }

    void ShowOnlyDataView1();
    void ShowOnlyDataView2();
    void ShowOnlyDataView3();

    // Other methods, properties, etc...
}
```

The MainView class would inherit from `Form` and its own interface. Here I have shown the instantiated DataGridViews being passed in via the form's constructor:

```
public class MainView : Form, IMainView
{
    public IDataGridView1 DataView1 { get; set; }
    public IDataGridView2 DataView2 { get; set; }
    public IDataGridView3 DataView3 { get; set; }

    TableLayoutPanel layoutPanel;

    public MainView(IDataGridView1 dataView1, IDataGridView2 dataView2,
                    IDataGridView3 dataView3)
    {
        this.DataView1 = dataView1;
        this.DataView2 = dataView2;
        this.DataView3 = dataView3;

        layoutPanel = new TableLayoutPanel();
        // Define your layout panel here.

        // Add your controls to layoutPanel.

        // Add layoutPanel to the MainView.
        Controls.Add(layoutPanel);

        // Rest of constructor...
    }

    // Hides other views and show DataView1.
    public void ShowOnlyDataView1()
    {
        DataView2.Hide();
        DataView3.Hide();
        DataView1.Show();
    }

    // Hides other views and show DataView2.
    public void ShowOnlyDataView2()
    {
        // Etc...
    }

    // Hides other views and show DataView3.
    public void ShowOnlyDataView3()
    {
       // Etc...
    }

    // Other Methods etc...
}
```

Here is an example of the your Main method. You will want to instantiate each DataGridView and pass these into your MainView:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IDataModel dataModel = new DataModel();
    IDataGridView1 dataView1 = new DataGridView1();
    IDataGridView2 dataView2 = new DataGridView2();
    IDataGridView3 dataView3 = new DataGridView3();
    IMainView mainView = new MainView(dataView1, dataView2, dataView3);
    DataGridPresenter1 dataPresenter1 = new DataGridPresenter1(dataView1, dataModel);
    DataGridPresenter2 dataPresenter2 = new DataGridPresenter2(dataView2, dataModel);
    DataGridPresenter3 dataPresenter3 = new DataGridPresenter3(dataView3, dataModel);
    MainPresenter mainPresenter = new MainPresenter(mainView, dataModel);
}
```

Something to that effect.

So your three DataGridViews are displayed within your MainView, and all four views are accessed by their own Presenters.